# DHCP Configuration options

Tags: windows, networking, router, ip, dhcp

I want to use Windows Server 2019 as my DHCP server for my company network, the question that I have is do I have to assign static IP addresses to both the Cisco switch and the router provided by my ISP?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign static IP addresses to all network infrastructure devices and servers.  If for some reason, their IP changed due to a lease expiring, you could experience outages and it would make troubleshooting difficult.  Just imagine if the DHCP server went down, or someone else accidentally plugged in a device into the network with its own DHCP server, like a home router.  Static IPs are the way to go.

DHCP should be used for devices like desktops, laptops, tablets, phones, etc.  Basically, for devices that are more likely to be removed from the network, replaced, etc.  You can do DHCP reservations, if you have a large enough pool of IPs and feel a 'static' dynamic IP address would make administration easier.

Comment: Thanks, for your response. The reason I  asked is because usually the router provided by the Internet Service Provider comes with an IP which I thought I should not change.